# Bitcoin core behind Tor Hidden service problem

Tags: tor, services

Recently I had to reinstall/compile Bitcoin Core in my freshly installed Debian Buster laptop.
I followed instructions here for method 2 at the bottom of the site:
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Setting_up_a_Tor_hidden_service

But shortly after I started my node, I noticed that the command

```
bitcoin-cli getnetworkinfo
```

was reporting 2 onion addresses at the bottom of the returned JSON object, at section *localaddresses*.

```
    {
      "address": "rs6srmllckfcveu2.onion",
      "port": 8333,
      "score": 6
    },
    {
      "address": "53hhdjgv4jailcee.onion",
      "port": 8334,
      "score": 4
    }
  ],
  "warnings": ""
```

These are my settings related to Bitcoin Core and Tor

Bitcoin Core config file

```
proxy=127.0.0.1:9050
listen=1
bind=127.0.0.1
externalip=53hhdjgv4jailcee.onion
onlynet=onion
port=8334
```

and in /etc/tor/torrc

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/bitcoin-service
HiddenServiceVersion 2
HiddenServicePort 8334 127.0.0.1:8333
```

I also added this to
but these lines are for c-lightning node configuration, so I assume they play no role for Bitcoin Core configuration regarding method 2.

```
SocksPort 9050

CookieAuthentication 1
CookieAuthFileGroupReadable 1
CookieAuthFile /run/tor/control.authcookie
```

Inside */var/lib/tor/bitcoin-service/hostname* I can see only one onion address which is the one in my Bitcoin Core config file.

I already tried to delete my bitcoin *onion_private_key* file and also deleted my */var/lib/tor/bitcoin-service* folder, but still 2 onion addresses are showing up.
So, where is it Bitcoin Core picking up the other onion address?
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `HiddenServiceDir` `HiddenServiceVersion` and `HiddenServicePort` from _/etc/tor/torrc_ ?

Comment: I'll try today after work and will let you know @Prayank

Comment: @Prayank if I remove those lines, the service won't be controlled by Tor any more, if I understand correctly. Which was the point of that config. However, I'm not using that config any more. If I get back to it, I'll come back to this thread. Thank you!